# problem with storing in pivot table with Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I have a project and user tables and the user joins a project by filling a form where they enter the project's code.
what I'm trying to do is to find the project by that code and store its id and user id in the pivot table project_user.
here's my code

```
//app\Http\Controllers\ProjectController.php
public function join(Request $request)
    {
        $code=$request->get('code');
        $project = Project::where('code',$code)->get();
        $userid=auth()->id();
        $project->users()->attach($userid);
        return redirect('/dashboard')->with('success', 'Project joined!'); 
    }


//app\Models\project.php
class Project extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'project_name',
        'description',
        'code'       
    ];
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

**this is what I've got**
[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Fn6y.png)/[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QR0GN.png)

this method

> $project->users()->attach($userid);

worked for me when the user creates a project

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'project_name'=>'required',
            'code'=>'required'
        ]);

        $userid=auth()->id();
        $project = new Project([
            'project_name' => $request->get('project_name'),
            'description' => $request->get('description'),
            'code' => $request->get('code')
        ]);
        
        $project->save();
        $project->users()->attach($userid);
        
        return redirect('/dashboard')->with('success', 'Project saved!');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `$project = Project::where('code',$code)->get();`, you get a `Collection` instance. That could be an array of multiple elements, or an array of 1 element (or even zero).

ALWAYS when you call `->get()` on some query, it returns a Collection.

So in order to get the actual project for that code (assuming that is a unique column), you can use:

```php
$project = Project::where('code', $code)->first();
```

Now, `$project` is either a single `Project` or `null` if it does not exist.